# Ionic Plugin Creation Using Plugman

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugman

I'm new to Ionic and Cordova. I need to create a plugin for ionic using Cordova and integrate it in sample ionic app.

Steps I Followed are:

Created a simple ionic plugin using plugman

```
plugman create --name SayHello --plugin_id cordova-plugin-sayhello -plugin_version 0.0.1
```

Added android platform to above plugin.

```
cd SayHello/ && plugman platform add --platform_name android
```

Now I want to integrate this plugin into my ionic app.

```
ionic cordova plugin add ../SayHello
```

In my ionic app inside Home.ts, I wrote this piece of code.

```
declare var cordova: any;
var success = function(result) {
  console.log(result);
}
var failure = function(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
cordova.plugins.HelloWorld.coolMethod("SayHelloTest", success, failure);
```

The problem is I cannot call any function from success or failure in the ionic app.

like if I call function doSomething from success:

```
var success = function(result) {
   doSomething(result);
}
```

It Shows Error doSomething function not found. It can only print in console.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create success as the class function and either send it as a bound function or call inside arrow.

```ts
declare var cordova:any;

class HomePage{
    //constructor etc...
    doSomething(res:any){
    }

    success(result){
        this.doSomething(result);
    }
    failure(err){}
    //..
    //call
    callCordovaFunction(){
        cordova.plugins.HelloWorld.coolMethod("SayHelloTest", this.success.bind(this), this.failure.bind(this));
    //or
        cordova.plugins.HelloWorld.coolMethod("SayHelloTest", (res)=>this.success(res),(err)=>this.failure(err));    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I am still unable to set text in UI Element. Even there is no error.

Comment: You will need to show an [mcve] in another question. There isn't enough info to tell why a text isn't shown in UI

Answer (score 0):

After creating the plugin, it is theoretically possible to import it also with plugman in order to do what you're trying to do. I have read the command is:
`plugman install --platform android --project projectPlatformPath --plugin pluginPath`

Anyway, this **didn't work for me** when I tried and also makes your plugin uncomfortable to use. It is probably a better idea to create an ionic wrapper for your plugin with `gulp` and copy it into your project's `node_modules/@ionic-native`. This way you would be able to inject it like the other plugins you just add with `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-name-here`. This is also the recommended way by Ionic.

Detailed instructions would be long to write here. Just **visit [this tutorial](https://joangape.blogspot.com/2019/11/create-custom-cordova-plugin-for-ionic4.html)** and follow the step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

To install plugman, you must have [node](http://nodejs.org/) installed on your machine. Then you can run the following command from anywhere in your environment to install plugman globally, so that it is available from any directory:

```
$ npm install -g plugman
```

Once you have installed Plugman and have created a Cordova project, you can start adding plugins to the platform with:

```
$ plugman create --name SayHello --plugin_id cordova-plugin-sayhello -plugin_version 0.0.1
```