# Ionic 4 : How import a custom plugin

Tags: objective-c, plugins, ionic4

I create a ionic plugin with Plugman command.
My plugin is: SayHello

[image]

This is the content of SayHello.js :

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

exports.coolMethod = function (arg0, success, error) {
    exec(success, error, 'SayHello', 'coolMethod', [arg0]);
};
```

And this is the content of SayHello.m :

```
/********* SayHello.m Cordova Plugin Implementation *******/

#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@interface SayHello : CDVPlugin {
  // Member variables go here.
}

- (void)coolMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
@end

@implementation SayHello

- (void)coolMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    NSLog(@"===============> Hello Seikida !");

    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
    NSString* echo = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    if (echo != nil && [echo length] > 0) {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:echo];
    } else {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];
    }

    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}

@end
```

I installed my custom plugin on my ionic project (ionic 4) :

[image]

Everything is good (= I don't have error when I run my project on my devise) but I don't know how to call the coolMethod.

To create my plugin, I follow this topic: [Ionic Plugin Creation Using Plugman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53113715/ionic-plugin-creation-using-plugman)

but they used a old ionic version (example: there is not Home.ts file on ionic 4).

Can you help me to understand how to use my plugin on the home.page.ts ?
How import my plugin ?
(And do you have a example?)

Thank you

Comment: I'm in the same situation but for Android... did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to to is create an Ionic wrapper for your plugin, copy it into your Ionic project, import it and register the provider. After that you will be able to inject your plugin and use it.
Summing up, you have to do this:

1. Import the ionic-native repo (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native)
2. Create an Ionic wrapper with the tool `gulp` inside the ionic-native directory and set it up
3. Compile the wrapper and copy the result into your project under the directory `node_modules/@ionic-native`
4. Register the provider in `app.module.ts` (you probably have done this before when installing some other existing plugin)
5. Import and inject the plugin in `my-page.page.ts` (also probably done before)
6. Enjoy

The setting up of the plugin is specially tricky and you have to be very careful with the naming of things in `src/@ionic-native/plugins/my-plugin/index.ts`. If you don't do it right, you'll get a "plugin not installed" error on runtime. In this case, correct a repeat step 3.

You probably need more detailed information. Following the **step by step guide in [this tutorial](https://joangape.blogspot.com/2019/11/create-custom-cordova-plugin-for-ionic4.html)** I wrote you wont get lost. You can probably jump to step 5, considering where you got stuck, but I recommend to read from the beginning to make yourself in context.

Hope this helps!